# concurrent append to hdfs file in spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I get ex that failed to append_file file is busy hdfs_non_map_reduce

i take records from kafka through spark and put it in cassandra and hdfs
`stream.map(somefunc).saveToCassandra`

```
stream.map(somefunc).foreachRDD(rdd => 
fs.append.write(rdd.collect.mkstring.getBytes)
fs.close)
```

replication factor in hdfs is 1, i use one node cluster
spark standalone cluster with 2 workers

i do not want `rdd.toDF.save("append")` because it makes a lot of files.
Any ideas. 
Or may be hdfs has method to check, if file is busy bu another task?

Answer (score 0):

> i do not want rdd.toDF.save("append") because it makes a lot of files

Use `rdd.repartition(1).toDF.save("append")` to reduce the number of output files to 1

Answer (score 0):

This is also not good for me, it makes file for each rdd, but i want one big file for and hour or day

So now i use try catch finally scheme on my cluster

```
try {
fs.append.write(rdd.collect.mkstring.getBytes)
}
catch {
case ex: IOException => fs.wait(1000)
}
finally {
fs.close
}
```

but i think that i have exceptions, but it works properlly, i write 100k msg to kafka and file on hdfs also have so, and this way i control this, but i thought, that in this way, if ex, msgs not write, and fs.close

Comment: I see, that in this way, saving to cassandra does workers, but saving to hdfs does driver. Why?